# Why use ports in interfaces?

Tags: system-verilog

The SystemVerilog LRM (IEEE 1800-2017) describes ports in interfaces as follows:

> One limitation of simple interfaces is that the nets and variables declared within the interface are only used to connect to a port with the same nets and variables. To share an external net or variable, one that makes a connection from outside the interface as well as forming a common connection to all module ports that instantiate the interface, an interface port declaration is required. The difference between nets or variables in the interface port list and other nets or variables within the interface is that only those in the port list can be connected externally by name or position when the interface is instantiated. Interface port declaration syntax and semantics are the same as those of modules (see 23.2.2).

What is the first sentence saying exactly? I don't see the limitation.

In the second sentence, what is an example of an external signal? How do you decided whether a signal should be declared inside the interface or as a port to the interface? The text used in the LRM just doesn't click for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is shown with the simple_bus example that follows the section of the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) you quoted.

There are two instances of the interface `sb_intf1` and `sb_intf2` each creating a unique set of internal signals (req, int, ...). If `clk` had also been declared as internal signal, there would also be two clock signals. What's not shown in the example is the code generating the clock signal. That could have been in the `top` module or another module. They would have needed to add continuous assignments to get the generated clock signal to each the internal `clk` in each interface instance.

By putting the *shared* signals in the interface in their port declarations, it makes it much easier to join the common signals.

```
interface simple_bus (input logic clk); // Define the interface
  logic req, gnt;
  logic [7:0] addr, data;
  logic [1:0] mode;
  logic start, rdy;
endinterface: simple_bus
module memMod(simple_bus a); // Uses just the interface
  logic avail;
  always @(posedge a.clk) // the clk signal from the interface
    a.gnt <= a.req & avail; // a.req is in the 'simple_bus' interface
endmodule
module cpuMod(simple_bus b);
  ...
endmodule
module top;
  logic clk = 0;
  simple_bus sb_intf1(clk); // Instantiate the interface
  simple_bus sb_intf2(clk); // Instantiate the interface
  memMod mem1(.a(sb_intf1)); // Reference simple_bus 1 to memory 1
  cpuMod cpu1(.b(sb_intf1));
  memMod mem2(.a(sb_intf2)); // Reference simple_bus 2 to memory 2
  cpuMod cpu2(.b(sb_intf2));
endmodule
```

Comment: Following up on that, since clk is generated externally, from the point of view of the interfaces, then the clk port in those interfaces should be declared as inputs?

Comment: That is correct.